# Elastic Search, from-start doesn't work correctly

Tags: elasticsearch

I am going to fetch some records between two dates using Elastic Search query.

First, I check the number of records between two dates to know whether it is greater than 10000 or not. If it is, i try to fetch them 10000 by 10000.

```
    //get count
    var result_count = client.Count<TelegramMessageStructure>(s => s
    .AllTypes()
    .AllIndices()
    .Query(q => q
    .DateRange(r => r
    .Field(f => f.messageDate)
    .GreaterThanOrEquals("2018-06-03 00:00:00.000")
    .LessThan("2018-06-03 00:59:00.000")
    )
    )
    );
    long count = result_count.Count; //count = 27000
```

it returns 27000. So I want to fetch them 10000 by 10000. I use this query to do that:

```
    int MaxMessageCountPerQuery=10000;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += MaxMessageCountPerQuery)
    {
        client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
        // No change whether the client is renewed or not
        var result = client.Search<TelegramMessageStructure>(s => s
           .AllTypes()
           .AllIndices()
           .MatchAll()
           .From(i)
           .Size(MaxMessageCountPerQuery)
           .Sort(ss => ss.Ascending(p => p.id))
           .Query(q => q
               .DateRange(r => r
                   .Field(f => f.messageDate)
                   .GreaterThanOrEquals("2018-06-03 00:00:00.000")
                   .LessThan("2018-06-03 00:59:00.000")
               )
           )
       );
       //when i=0, result.documents contains 10000 records otherwise it has 0

    }
```

In The first round, when i=0, `result.documents` contains 10000 records otherwise it contains 0 records.

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this link:
[scroll in elastic net-api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/scroll.html)

Your codes should contains below steps:

1- Search with all parameters that you need plus **.Scroll("5m")** (I assume *from(0)* and *size(10000)* is set too and save response in *result* variable)

2- Now you have first 10000 records (in *result.Documents*)

3- For receive more records, you should use **ScrollId** param to get more results. (Each call of bellow code give you next 10000 records)

```
var result_new = client.Scroll<TelegramMessageStructure>("10m", result.ScrollId);
```

In fact, your codes should be like this:

```
        int MaxMessageCountPerQuery=10000;

        client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
        // No change whether the client is renewed or not
        var result = client.Search<TelegramMessageStructure>(s => s
           .AllTypes()
           .AllIndices()
           .MatchAll()
           .From(i)
           .Size(MaxMessageCountPerQuery)
           .Sort(ss => ss.Ascending(p => p.id))
           .Query(q => q
               .DateRange(r => r
                   .Field(f => f.messageDate)
                   .GreaterThanOrEquals("2018-06-03 00:00:00.000")
                   .LessThan("2018-06-03 00:59:00.000")
               )
           )
           .Scroll("5m") // Add this parameter
       );

       // TODO some code:
       // save and use result.Documents

      for (int i = 0; i < result.Total; i += MaxMessageCountPerQuery)
      {
         var result_new = client.Scroll<TelegramMessageStructure>("10m", result.ScrollId); // Add this line to loop , Each loop you can get next 10000 record.
         // TODO some code:
         // save and use result_new.Documents
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has a default index.max_result_window = 10000 and it's well explained at 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html

> To understand why deep paging is problematic, let’s imagine that we
>   are searching within a single index with five primary shards. When we
>   request the first page of results (results 1 to 10), each shard
>   produces its own top 10 results and returns them to the coordinating
>   node, which then sorts all 50 results in order to select the overall
>   top 10.
>
> Now imagine that we ask for page 1,000—results 10,001 to 10,010.
>   Everything works in the same way except that each shard has to produce
>   its top 10,010 results. The coordinating node then sorts through all
>   50,050 results and discards 50,040 of them!
>
> You can see that, in a distributed system, the cost of sorting results
>   grows exponentially the deeper we page. There is a good reason that
>   web search engines don’t return more than 1,000 results for any query.